# Best Way to form this query

Tags: mysql, sql

Team,

I have three tables.

myTransTable,myMasterTable 1, MymyMasterTable 2

myTransTable have a lot of  entries  'Rank.No '  auto incerement field is to identify indvidual records . 'U.Name' holds user name. Each user can have multiple records in this table . But the most recent transaction of a user can be  find by the max value for Rank.No after grouping by 'U.Name'

Once this max record i.e recent transaction is fetched their asociated data  needs to fetched from other  tables

How can this be done in most efficent  way.

> 1.myTransTable(fields Rank.No(auto increment field),Name,RecNum,uname,date,type)
>
> 2.myMasterTable1  (RecNum,Recowner,recdate)
>
> 3.MymyMasterTable2 (uName,age ,address,contact num)

I tried these  ways  for selection the max record and fetch the assocated data from other  tables

> 1. max records as a  view and fetch data from other tables using normal query
> 2. Max records and associated data itself as a view and select data as needed

Which is best way to have minimum execution time?

My queries are which is the  best way to find the max.

Option one

```
select a.`RecNum`,a.`Name`,a.`Date`, a.`type`"+
            "from myTransTable a "+
            "INNER JOIN "+
            "(SELECT RecNumMAX(`Rank.No`) AS maxserialnum FROM myTransTable "+
            "GROUP BY RecNumMAX)groupedRecNumMAX "+
            " ON "+
            " a.RecNum = groupedPWO.RecNum  "+
            "AND "+
            "a.`Rank.No`  = groupedRecNumMAX.maxserialnum "+
```

Option two

```
Select a.`RecNum`,a.`Name`,a.`Date`, a.`type`"+` 
FROM                   from myTransTable a

WHERE                    s.`RecNum` in(select MAX(`RecNum`)
       from               myTransTable 
       group by       RecNum)
```

Comment: Depend on excute plan..

Comment: your first query is syntactically wrong  ..  ?? RecNumMAX(`Rank.No`)??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a suggestion adn is related  to  your first query  .. that seems contain wrong reference to table and column  name

looking to you code you should use a query like this

```
select a.`RecNum`
    ,a.`Name`
    ,a.`Date`
    , a.`type`
  from myTransTable a 
  INNER JOIN   (
      SELECT RecNum, MAX(`Rank.No`) AS maxserialnum 
      FROM myTransTable 
      GROUP BY RecNum 
  )  g ON  a.RecNum =g.RecNum  AND  a.`Rank.No`  = g..maxserialnum
```

and this with proper index  ..  on RecNum, and `Rank.No` should be the most performant (you can check in explain plain and with proper execution test)

*You should not use column name with dot separated  name  as Rank.No  .. use Rank_No isteand and also for column name the is preferred lowercase not and not a mix of UpperOrLower case use underscore for separate the word instead*